# How to handle RejectedExecutionException with ThreadPoolExecutor in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

What is the best way to handle `RejectedExecutionException` while using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` in Java?

I want to ensure that the task submitted should not be overlooked and should surely get executed. As of now there are no hard real time requirements to get the task done.

One of the things I thought could be done was waiting in a loop till I know that there is space in the runnable queue, and then go on and add it to the queue.

Would be glad if people can share their experiences.

Adding the possible solution I though of:

```
while(executor.getQueue().remainingCapacity <= 0){
// keep looping
Thread.sleep(100);
};
//if the loop exits ,indicates that we have space in the queue hence 
//go ahead and add to the queue 
executor.execute(new ThreadInstance(params));
```

Comment: This will create a race condition if more than one thread is trying to do this.  It will also burn a cpu which could mean it take longer for the executor to clear the queue. e.g. if there is only one CPU for the adder and the executor, this could be disastrous.

Comment: From the architecture there would be just one thread doing this, and to handle CPU time eatup, I am making the thread sleep.How does this look now?

Comment: Sleeping, even for a short time (even 1 - 10 ms) is far better than not. 100 ms is a good value too. This is fine if you only have one publishing thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change the behaviour of your queue. e.g.

```
public class MyBlockingQueue<E> extends ArrayBlockingQueue<E> {
    private final long timeoutMS;

    public MyBlockingQueue(int capacity, long timeoutMS) {
        super(capacity);
        this.timeoutMS = timeoutMS;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean offer(E e) {
        try {
            return super.offer(e, timeoutMS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This will wait for the queue to drain before giving up.

Comment: Cant I simply do something like while(executor.getQueue().remainingCapacity <= 0){// keep looping};
//if the loop exits ,indicates that we have space in the queue hence //go ahead and add to the queue
executor.execute(new ThreadInstance(params));
This seems to be a solution without having to creating my own instance of ArrayBlockingQueue.

Comment: You have a race condition if you do.  There is no guarantee that another thread might not fill the queue attempting to do the same thing. You don't have to create your own ArrayBlockingQueue, you can copy mine. ;)

Comment: I tried this, but the exucute() function on the ThreadPoolExecuter got blocking. I read that it depends on the Executer configuration. any idea on how to make in not blocking?

Comment: It only block if your RejectedExecutionHandler blocks. The default REH throws an exception so you must have changed it to block. e.g.  CallerRunsPolicy will cause the Executor to block.

Answer (score 2):

If you have constrained your thread pool to only allow a certain number of concurrent threads (generally a good thing), then the application needs to somehow push-back on the calling code, so when you receive a RejectedExecutionException from the ThreadPoolExecutor you need to indicate this to the caller and the **caller** will need to handle the retry.

An analogous situation is a web server under heavy load. A client connects, the web server should return a 503 - Service Unavailable (generally a temporary condition) and the client decides what to do about it.